# Edit conf file in Ubuntu through one line command

Tags: bash, apache, ubuntu, vim, sed

I want to change my default web root folder of apache2 web server, but through command line from a script I am making.

I know to do it through nano/vim and then go to the line and change it manually, but I want to make it by a command line.

I though about some thing like (the syntax is wrong - I know - just to make my point):

```
vim /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf | find 'DocumentRoot /var/www' | replace 'DocumentRoot /var/www/myFolder'
```

maybe not with vim but other ??
Any Idea ?

Thanks

Comment: user1902346 did one of the answers help? ✓

Answer (score 1):

You should use `sed` with the substitute command for that kind of operation.

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-0

I don't have a unix machine at hand but something like that should work (using # rather than the usual / as separator):

```
sed 's#/var/www#/var/www/MyFolder#' /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

Even if it is not your question, since your initial question mentioned Vim, you can also use substitute from inside Vim

Like

```
:%s #/var/war#/var/www/MyFolder#g

% means search in the whole file
g means globally : it will replace multiple instance if the string is found multiple times
```

Comment: Acutally you can modifiy the file vim automatically: `vim -c "%s #/var/www#/var/www/MyFolder#g" -c wq /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`

Answer (score 1):

Use sed with argument `-i`.

```
 sed -i 's-/var/www-&/MyFolder-' /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

Argument `-i` enables in-place editing.

Comment: Thanks guys. Seems that sed will do the work. I wasn't familiar with it.